# How to access confluence on remote server

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, virtual-machine, confluence

I have Confluence installed on my ubuntu server(vm) successfully. It prompts me to visit it in browser on http://localhost:8090. The localhost of my vm has an IP of 10.0.0.15. I tried to visit http://10.0.0.15:8090 in browser and it doesn't work. Anyone familiar with this issue when installing Confluence? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Need help and attention please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confluence server uses the port 8090 by default. You need to allow TCP port 8090 in the Inbound rules for your VM. 
You can then be able to access confluence via browser using your IP address and port.
For example: http://10.x.x.x:8090

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem installing Confluence on a remote server. The confluence server that is serving the web interface required for setup is running on the local loopback interface only it seems.

This means you need to start a browser on the same host and then you can access http://127.0.0.1:8090 from there. You cannot access it via a remote IP (like 10.0.0.15).

Sadly, I found no documentation on the Confluence Linux website that would tell you how to make it listen on the public IP as well (this would have security implications, of course, they would need to make you enter a token you received on the command line or something to ensure others cannot use it).

So the only solutions are to run a web browser on the remote machine.

1. Running a browser like Chrome or Firefox which requires a GUI could be done via

   - X11 forwarding through SSH or
   - via a remote desktop service on
     the server, like VNC
2. by running a text mode browser like links2 on the server

Note that the option 1 requires tons of GUI stuff to be installed on the server (especially the VNC option) and may not be an option.

The text mode browsers have problems with many modern web sites it seems, but I managed to install Confluence this way. (It felt a bit shaky and unprofessional though.)

Answer (score 0):

this is not a Confluence config issue - you should configure your VM, so it uses NAT - this way it will get an IP address from your DHCP. 10.0.0.15 is not visible from your host computer.

Comment: I'm sure my vm is using bridge because I'm using WinSCP to connect it from host. I also have a Strongloop running on this vm and it uses localhost initialy. I set export HOST=0.0.0.0 then I can use 10.0.0.15 from host to visit Strongloop. But this doesn't work for Confluence.